# waiting screen while redirecting to other domain page

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I have one page from which i have to redirect to a page which is in some other application or can say in other domain.I want waiting screen till the page is loaded.I want to do it by jquery.Can any one help me-

Answer (score 1):

[blockUI](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/) would be an option

eg.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3; URL=http://www.mydestination.com/">
        <!-- script include for jQuery and blockUI -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $.blockUI({
                    message: 'redirecting'
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

but if you want to keep the overlay on the redirected page while it is loaded, this would be only possible if you use eg. an iframe. but with that, you would have other problems eg. height, width of iframe